# Does resize on a std::vector<int> set the new elements to zero?

Tags: c++, c++11, integer, stdvector, value-initialization

Consider

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> foo;
    foo.resize(10);
    // are the elements of foo zero?
}
```

Are the elements of `foo` all zero? I think they are from C++11 onwards. But would like to know for sure.

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize): *If the current size is less than `count`, additional default-inserted elements are appended*

Comment: Absolutely. But I'm struggling with what default-inserted means from C++11.

Comment: You can think of it as **value initialized**.

Comment: Is `int a;` default initialised? Or is `static int a;` default initialised?

Comment: @pptaszni No, they are value initialized. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultInsertable).

Comment: Seems so: [resize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) -> [default insertable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultInsertable) (note there the explicit requrirement for a custom allocator on not needing zeroing out).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are the elements of `foo` all zero?

Yes, this can be seen from [std::vector::resize documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) which says:

> If the current size is less than count,
>
> 1. additional **default-inserted** elements are appended

And from [defaultInsertable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultInsertable):

> By default, this will call placement-new, as by `::new((void*)p) T()` (until C++20)`std::construct_at(p)` (since C++20) (that is, **value-initialize the object pointed to by `p`**). If value-initialization is undesirable, for example, if the object is of non-class type and zeroing out is not needed, it can be avoided by providing a custom `Allocator::construct`.

(emphasis mine)

Note the `T()` in the above quoted statement. This means that after the resize `foo.resize(10);`, elements of `foo` will contain value `0` as they were **value initialized**.

Answer (score 6):

Simple answer: **Yes**

Long answer:

> If n is greater than the current container size, the content is
> expanded by inserting at the end as many elements as needed to reach a
> size of n. If val is specified, the new elements are initialized as
> copies of val, otherwise, they are **value-initialized**

Now, as value initialization from the standard we get:

> — if T is a class type (clause 9) with a user-declared constructor
> (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the
> initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default
> constructor); — if T is a non-union class type without a user-declared
> constructor, then every non-static data member and base-class
> component of T is value-initialized; — if T is an array type, then
> each element is value-initialized; — otherwise, the object is
> zero-initialized

`int` falls on otherwise, so it is **zero initialized**

Comment: don't forget attribution: you quoted https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/
(which is only correct for default allocators)

Answer (score 3):

This member function is overloaded the following way

```
void resize(size_type sz);
void resize(size_type sz, const T& c);
```

For the first function the effect is

> Effects: If sz <= size(), equivalent to calling pop_back() size() - sz
> times. **If size() < sz, appends sz - size() default-inserted elements
> to the sequence**

That is there is used the expression T(). If elements are of the type `int` then they are zero-initialized.

Comment: So in my specific case they all have the value 0? Sorry to be so specific, but "zero-initialised" is a bit like what happens to `static int a;`?

Comment: @P45Imminent In the example given in your question after `foo.resize(10);` all elements will have value `0`.

Comment: @P45Imminent You are right. All elements will have the value 0.